# How to fix unresponsive Terminal

Tags: command-line, bashrc

My Terminal does Not respond. I can Open it but when I try to type something, it gets ignored. I cant See the letters on the Terminal - They are Not hidden.
I tried 2 other Terminals, Same Problem.
I had to do a lot of Updates the last few days, also I had to edit the bashrc file, maybe thats the cause.

Answer (score 2):

‘.bashrc’ is executed when you start a Terminal session so, yes, that is a probable cause. You’ve likely added something in there which is not finishing and the Terminal session is waiting for it to complete.

Please update your question with the contents of your .bashrc

Comment: Something in your `~/.bashrc` is awaiting input. The terminal control characters `Ctrl-D` (hold `Ctrl` key and type `d`)  End-Of-File, `Ctrl-C` Interrupt, `Ctrl-Z` Suspend may help you break out, but you'll probably have a partially set-up environment. Use it only to fix your `~/ .bashrc`, test it with ` bash -x ~/.bashrc`. When it works, logoff and login cleanly.